# Retrieving status from bulk job load?

Tags: apex, bulk, jobid

Is there any way to get the status of the bulk job load using job id for each job via apex?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you mean using the Bulk API or not, but if you are I think you can probably do this using a callout in Apex (if you're not, please disregard this answer), for example:

```
String pod = 'eu11';
String baseUrl = pod + '.salesforce.com';
String endpoint = baseUrl + '/services/async/36.0/job/' + jobId + '/batch/' + batchId;
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setTimeout(60000);
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('X-SFDC-Session', UserInfo.getSessionId());

HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

More info in page 43 of [this](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_asynch.pdf) document.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to select Status field and other info from AsyncApexJob standard object via SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, Status, CompletedDate FROM AsyncApexJob where Id = :JobId
```